# Primefaces DataTable not updating after passing parameters between Managed Beans

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, glassfish-3, managed-property

I'm currently working with Primefaces datatable with simple CRUD operations. This Datatable shows tasks of a work list that's selected previously in another datatable that show worklists of projects. To get the selected worklist, i inject the WorkListManagedBean into the TaskManagedBean. When i create or delete a task from the selected work list, it was done successfully in the database but the datatable is not updation :(. Here is my Task Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "taskMBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TaksMBean implements Serializable {

   @ManagedProperty("#{workListMBean}")
   private WorkListMBean workListMBean;
   @Inject
   private TaskBusinessLocal taskBusinessLocal;
   @Inject
   private ResourceBusinessLocal resourceBusinessLocal;
   private String description, code;
   private Date startDate, endDate;
   private Status status;
   private List<Resource> resources, resourceslist;
   private List<Task> filteredTasks, tasks;
   private Task selectedTask;
   private WorkList selectedWorkList;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
     selectedTask = new Task();
     selectedWorkList = workListMBean.getSelectedWorkList();
    }

   public List<Task> getTasks() {
     return tasks=workListMBean.getTasksList();
    }

   public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
     this.workListMBean.setTasks(tasks) ;
    }

    public List<Resource> getAllResources() {
     return resourceBusinessLocal.allResources();
    }

    public Status[] getAllStatus() {
     return Status.values();
    }

    public String addTask() {
      taskBusinessLocal.addTask(description, code, startDate,  
         endDate,status,    
       selectedWorkList, resources);
       return "index";
     }

    public String upDateTask() {
      taskBusinessLocal.updateTask(selectedTask);
      return "index";
     }

    public String deleteTask() {
      taskBusinessLocal.deleteTask(selectedTask);
      return "index";
     }

    public Status getStatus() {
      return status;
     }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
      this.status = status;
     }

    public String getDescription() {
     return description;
     }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
      this.description = description;
     }

    public Date getStartDate() {
       return startDate;
     }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
     }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
     }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
       this.endDate = endDate;
     }

    public String getCode() {
     return code;
     }

    public void setCode(String code) {
     this.code = code;
     }

    public List<Resource> getResources() {
      return resources;
     }

    public void setResources(List<Resource> resources) {
      this.resources = resources;
     }

    public List<Resource> getResourceslist() {
      return resourceslist;
     }

    public void setResourceslist(List<Resource> resourceslist) {
      this.resourceslist = resourceslist;
     }

    public List<Task> getFilteredTasks() {
      return filteredTasks;
     }

    public void setFilteredTasks(List<Task> filteredTasks) {
     this.filteredTasks = filteredTasks;
     }

    public Task getSelectedTask() {
     return selectedTask;
     }

    public void setSelectedTask(Task selectedTask) {
      this.selectedTask = selectedTask;
     }

    public WorkListMBean getWorkListMBean() {
      return workListMBean;
     }

    public void setWorkListMBean(WorkListMBean workListMBean) {
     this.workListMBean = workListMBean;
     }

    public WorkList getSelectedWorkList() {
      return workListMBean.getSelectedWorkList();
    }
    }
```

and here is my JSF page:

```
 <ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

 <ui:define name="content">

    <h:form id="form">
        <p:contextMenu for="tasks">  
            <p:menuitem value="View" update="taskView" 
                        icon="ui-icon-search"   oncomplete="taskDialogView.show()"/>  
            <p:menuitem value="Update" update="taskUpdate"
                        icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"  
                        oncomplete="taskDialogUpdate.show()"/>  
            <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="tasks"
                        icon="ui-icon-close"  onclick="confirmation.show();"/>  
        </p:contextMenu>
        <p:dataTable id="tasks" value="#{taskMBean.tasks}" 
                     var="item"  rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,25,30" 
                     paginator="true" rows="10" 
                     filteredValue="#{taskMBean.filteredTasks}"
                     selection="#{taskMBean.selectedTask}" 
                     rowKey="#{item.id}" selectionMode="single">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":form:tasks, :form:taskView , 
                    :form:taskUpdate , :form:confirmDelete"/> 
        <f:facet name="header" >  
        <p:outputLabel value="List of WorkList (# 
                     {taskMBean.selectedWorkList.code}) tasks"/>
        </f:facet> 
        <p:column sortBy="#{item.description}" filterBy="#{item.description}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Description"/>
                </f:facet>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{item.description}">
                </p:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{item.code}" filterBy="#{item.code}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Code"/>
                </f:facet>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{item.code}">
                </p:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{item.startDate}" filterBy="#{item.startDate}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Start Date"/>

                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.startDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{item.endDate}" filterBy="#{item.endDate}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputLabel value="End Date"/>

                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.endDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="New Task" oncomplete="TaskDialogNew.show()" 
                   icon="ui-icon-star" title="New Task"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Delete Task"  actionListener="#
                  {taskMBean.deleteTask()}" update="tasks" icon="ui-icon-trash" 
                   style="margin-left: 5px"/>
                <p:button value="Back"  outcome="WorkLists.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-
                   arrowthick-1-w" style="margin-left: 900px"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:dialog header="Task Detail" widgetVar="taskDialogView" resizable="false"  
                  showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" style="position: absolute ;"  
                  id="dialogView">  
            <p:panelGrid id="taskView" columns="2" >  
                <f:facet name="header">  
                    <p:graphicImage value="/images/task.png"/>  
                </f:facet>
                <p:outputLabel value="Code:" />
                <p:outputLabel value="#{taskMBean.selectedTask.code}" title="Code" />
                <p:outputLabel value="Description:" />
                <p:outputLabel  value="#{taskMBean.selectedTask.description}" />
                <p:outputLabel value="Resources"/>
                <p:dataList value="#{taskMBean.selectedTask.resources}" var="item" 
                            itemType="square">
                            #{item.name} (#{item.code})
                </p:dataList>
                <p:outputLabel value="Start Date"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{taskMBean.selectedTask.startDate}" >
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                </p:outputLabel>
                <p:outputLabel value="End Date"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{taskMBean.selectedTask.endDate}" title="EndDate">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                </h:outputText> 
                <p:outputLabel value="Status"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{taskMBean.selectedTask.status}"/>
            </p:panelGrid>  
        </p:dialog>  
        <p:dialog header="task Update" widgetVar="taskDialogUpdate" resizable="false"  
                  showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" style="position: absolute ;" 
                  id="dialogUpdate">  
            <p:panelGrid id="taskUpdate" columns="2" >  
                <f:facet name="header">  
                    <p:graphicImage value="/images/task.png"/>  
                </f:facet> 
                <p:outputLabel value="Code:" for="code" style="width: 242px"/>
                <p:inputText id="code" value="#{taskMBean.selectedTask.code}" 
                   style="width: 236px" required="true" requiredMessage="The Code field 
                    is required."/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Description:" for="description" />
                <p:inputTextarea id="description" 
                   value="# {taskMBean.selectedTask.description}"  required="true" 
                   requiredMessage="The Description 
               field is required."/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Resources" for="resources"/>
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="resources" value="#
                  {taskMBean.selectedTask.resources}" style="width: 241px" 
                  label="Select Resources" required="true" requiredMessage="The List of 
                  Resources field is required.">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{taskMBean.allResources}" var="item"  
                  itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{selectedTask.resources}"  />
                    <f:converter 
                     converterId="com.gis.plannerplus.converters.ObjectConverterResource
                      " />
      </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Status" for="status"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="status" value="#{taskMBean.selectedTask.status}" 
                  style="width: 241px" required="true" requiredMessage="The customer 
                  field is required.">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{taskMBean.allStatus}" var="s" itemLabel="#
                {s.status}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:outputLabel for="startdate" value="Start "  />  
                <p:calendar  id="startdate" required="true" label="StartDate" 
                 style="width: 240px" binding="#{startdate}"
                             effect="fold"   value="#
                {taskMBean.selectedTask.startDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yy" >
                    <p:ajax process="startdate finishDate" update="toDateMsg" />
                </p:calendar>
                <p:outputLabel for="finishDate" value="End " />  
                <p:calendar  id="finishDate" label="FinishDate"  style="width: 240px" 
                 pattern="dd/MM/yy"
                             effect="fold"  value="#{taskMBean.selectedTask.endDate}" >
                    <f:attribute name="startDate" value="#{startdate.value}" />
                    <f:validator validatorId="validator.dateRangeValidator" />
                    <p:ajax process="startdate  finishDate" update="toDateMsg" />
                    <p:message for="finishDate" id="toDateMsg" >
                    </p:message>
                </p:calendar>
            </p:panelGrid> 
            <p:commandButton value="Clear" type="reset" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n"
            styleClass="ui-priority-primary"/>  
            <p:commandButton value="Save" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-circle-check" 
            styleClass="ui-priority-primary" action="#{taskMBean.upDateTask()}" />  
        </p:dialog>  
        <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDelete" message="Are you sure ?"  appendTo="@(body)"
                         header="Delete Task?" severity="alert" 
          widgetVar="confirmation" style="width: auto">  
            <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes" ajax="false"   />  
            <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No" onclick="confirmation.hide();" 
           type="button" />   
        </p:confirmDialog> 
    </h:form>


    <h:form id="newTaskForm">
        <p:dialog header="New Task" widgetVar="TaskDialogNew" resizable="false"  
                  showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" style="position: absolute ;" 
     id="dialogNewTask">  
            <p:panel id="panel">   
                <p:messages id="messages" />
                <p:panelGrid id="newTask" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" >  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <p:graphicImage value="/images/task.png"/>  
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Code:" for="code" />
                    <p:inputText  id="code" value="#{taskMBean.code}" style="width: 
       236px"  required="true" requiredMessage="The Code field is required."/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Description:" for="description" />
                    <p:inputTextarea id="description" value="#{taskMBean.description}" 
       style="width: 236px" required="true" requiredMessage="The Description field is
           required."/>


                    <p:outputLabel value="Resources" for="resources"/>
                    <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="resources" value="#{taskMBean.resources}"
       style="width: 241px" label="Select Resources"  >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{taskMBean.allResources}" var="item" 
        itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{resources}"   />
                        <f:converter 
       converterId="com.gis.plannerplus.converters.ObjectConverterResource" />
                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                       <p:outputLabel value="Status" for="status"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="status" value="#{taskMBean.status}" 
        style="width: 241px" required="true" requiredMessage="The customer field is 
        required.">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{taskMBean.allStatus}" var="s" 
        itemLabel="#{s.status}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:outputLabel for="startDate" value="Start "  />  
                    <p:calendar  id="startDate" required="true" label="StartDate" 
        style="width: 260px" binding="#{startDate}"
                                 effect="fold"   value="#{taskMBean.startDate}" 
          pattern="dd/MM/yy" >
                        <p:ajax process="startDate finishDate" update="toDateMsg" />
                    </p:calendar>
                    <p:outputLabel for="finishDate" value="End " />  
                    <p:calendar  id="finishDate" label="FinishDate"  style="width: 
          240px"
                                 effect="fold" required="true"  value="# 
                              {taskMBean.endDate}" >
                        <f:attribute name="startDate" value="#{startDate.value}" />
                        <f:validator validatorId="validator.dateRangeValidator" />
                        <p:ajax process="startDate  finishDate" update="toDateMsg" />
                        <p:message for="finishDate" id="toDateMsg" >
                        </p:message>
                    </p:calendar>
                </p:panelGrid> 
                <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Clear" icon="ui-icon-
            arrowrefresh-1-n" styleClass="ui-priority-primary"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" process="@form" 
            update=":form:tasks, :growl"  oncomplete=" handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, 
            args, 'TaskDialogNew','newTaskForm');" actionListener="#{taskMBean.addTask
           ()}"/> 
            </p:panel>
        </p:dialog>  
    </h:form>

    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="5000" />
    <script>
                function handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, dialogName, formName) {
                    dialog = jQuery('#' + dialogName);
                    if (args.validationFailed) {
                        dialog.effect("shake", {times: 3}, 100);
                    } else {
                        clearForm(formName);
                        TaskDialogNew.hide();
                        taskDialogUpdate.hide();

                    }
                }
                function clearForm(formName) {
                    jQuery('#' + formName).each(function() {
                        this.reset();
                    });
                }

    </script>
    </ui:define>
     </ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a JPQL query to retreive all tasks of the selected workList in the database. So, I defined a named query in the Task entity class:

```
   @NamedQuery(name = "task.findByWorklist", query = "select t from Task t where 
     t.worklist=:worklist"),
```

Then, I added this method in the Task manager class:

```
   @Override
   public List<Task> findByWorklist(WorkList worklist) {
     Query query = 
     em.createNamedQuery("task.findByWorklist").setParameter("worklist", worklist);
     return (List<Task>) query.getResultList();
   }
```

Finally, I placed getter and setter  methods in the TaskManagedBean class:

```
  public List<Task> getTasks() {
    return tasks=workListMBean.getTasksList();
  }

  public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    this.workListMBean.setTasks(tasks) ;
  }
```

by this method:

```
 public List<Task> getTasks() {
    return tasks=taskManagerLocal.findByWorkList(selectedWorkList);
 }
```

By this way, I could get tasks of the selected worklist from the database and the datatable is perfectly updating from the database after CRUD operation.

Answer (score 0):

Primeface has an Update attribute. In case of delete you can do following things:

```
 <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes" update="form:tasks"   />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rounak, I have already used the attribute "update" as shown in the xhtml code:

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" 
                     update=":form:tasks, :growl"  oncomplete=" handleSubmitRequest(xhr, 
                     status, args, 'TaskDialogNew','newTaskForm');" actionListener="#
                     {taskMBean.addTask()}"/>